# Can my Alien species be possible with real science?

Tags: biology, creature-design

They are blue to gray skinned with four eyes, two of which can see in infrared, three fingers and toes on each appendage, and reptilian-like ears (eardrums are external), as well as a hair color range similar to humans. They have nostrils where a human would, except that they are slits, they have systems similar to humans, but have different structures for everything. They live on an earth-like planet, but there is a singular ocean with an abundance of cyanobacteria. the seasons are longer than that on earth, as well as more extreme. Fresh water is scarce, but natural resources are abundant.

Comment: The universe is big, so of course it is "possible". I'm not sure there is sufficient distinctiveness in your description to say anything else.

Comment: It is probably going to be more productive to ask about the feasibility of a particular feature of your species, or the world they live in. Is there anything in particular that you are unsure of?

Comment: On how "seeing IR works" : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infrared_sensing_in_snakes

Comment: Add in a bad attitude, and it sounds like you've reinvented [Protheans](https://masseffect.fandom.com/wiki/Prothean). (except for the hair colours of course)

Comment: You've detailed nothing that isn't perfectly normal and extant in more than one species on Earth ~ accept _perhaps_ the infrared vision & that's just an extension of a little further into one end of the visible spectrum than anything normal on earth uses so not exactly a stretch ~ in short "why even ask?" yes of course.

Comment: @TimBII, These look nothing like that. Heads are more rounded, and wider

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are describing a **reptile**.

[image: lizard]
http://snakesarelong.blogspot.com/2012/09/snakes-that-can-see-without-eyes.html

This is a snake - that hole in front of its eye is the pit organ, that can "see" infrared.  It is the right color.  Slit nostrils are fine for a reptile that wants to conserve fresh water.  Internal systems are similar to ours since we are cousin vertebrates.  Re the world long extreme seasons sounds like the desert - good reptile territory; ditto fresh water scarcity.  Cyanobacteria abundance - that is us too!  Also the one ocean, except there is some land in the middle of it.

The only problem area is the hair.  But they could wear wigs.  And they should.

Comment: Hair is originally derived from scales, so it's not entirely infeasible that a reptile could develop hair.

Comment: @ArkensteinXII - you could make a case that feathers are the reptile version of hair. Definitely many colors!

Comment: And they should...ha ha ha.

Comment: @Willk At a stretch, you could even make a case than mammals are just heavily modified reptiles, so it would follow then that hair is the reptile version of hair. :P

Answer (score 1):

Virtually all of the features you've described for your aliens, perhaps barring the two sets of eyes, exist in some form on Earth already. Even then, having an extra set of eyes is likely to be perfectly feasible provided the metabolic budget allows for it and their brains have a larger visual cortex to allow for the extra processing power.

Eyes with infrared sensitivity exists in some fish and some frogs, though perhaps there's a reason it doesn't show up in other creatures - maybe it's just not useful enough to be worth the extra nutrients.

> Bullfrogs, who can see infrared light, have eyes that can see both above and below the water surface. Bullfrogs use Cyp27c1, an enzyme linked to vitamin A, to supercharge their infrared vision. Bullfrogs’ infrared seeing ability adapts depending on the environment. (https://sciencing.com/animals-can-see-infrared-light-6910261.html)

If your aliens are pseudo-reptiles, and as you say freshwater is scarce, perhaps the extra eyes are partly justified by glands similar to those in sea turtles to rid their bodies of excess salt?

Comment: A [Tuatara](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuatara) is a Reptile with 3 eyes.  A [Praying Mantis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mantis) and a [Starfish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starfish) each have 5 eyes.

Comment: [Saniwa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saniwa) had two ["third" eye](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parietal_eye)'s ~ fully evolve those into actual eyes & you're there, 4 eyes (differences in size & appearance to the other two "proper" eyes would seem reasonable of course).

Comment: ^ Their [placement & size](http://www.sci-news.com/paleontology/eocene-monitor-lizard-four-eyes-05874.html) is really very different of course.

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently researching vision in the infrared as well because my aliens spend most of their time in unlit burrows/mounds. As most of the other commenters have said, physical organs/features are adaptations to some part of a specie's environment - i.e. they aid in survival somehow. In mammals, fur helps regulate body temperature. Even in so-called hairless humans, the skin is not bald. It's covered in tiny hairs that still play a part in body temperature regulation.

https://www.sciencealert.com/watch-why-do-we-have-body-hair

If your alien has so many reptilian features, I can't help wondering why fur/feathers/hair would have evolved in the first place, or what role it would have played in the survival of the species.

If, however, the hair on the head is simply a feature that we humans relate to, then perhaps your aliens don't really need it at all.